# Debugger starts on node-tap instead of starting on test file

Tags: node.js, debugging, tap

I am trying to debug a test file in docker that runs with `node-tap`. I have added the running command, configured the debugger to connect to docker. Everything works, the tests are run and the debugger connects, but it debugs the `node-tap` module instead of the test file.
I have the following command:

```
"dev:test": "NODE_ENV=test tap --debug --node-arg=--loader=ts-node/esm --node-arg=--no-warnings --node-arg=--experimental-specifier-resolution=node --node-arg=--inspect-brk=0.0.0.0:3034 tests/e2e/component.test.ts --timeout=1200 --jobs=1"
```

And here is the `launch.json`

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
  {
    "name": "Attach to Docker",
    "type": "node",
    "request": "attach",
    "port": 3034,
    "address": "0.0.0.0",
    "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "remoteRoot": "/app",
    "restart": true,
    "outFiles": ["${workspaceFolder}/build/**/*.js"],
    "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**/*.js", "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/**/*.js"]
  }
]
```

}

When I run `yarn dev:test`, the debugger connects but I get sent to this:
[image]

Also when I add a breakpoint in my test file, it says: `some of the brakpoints could not be set`.
I found that adding the property `program` to the `launch.json` pointing to the file I want to run would solve the problem, but it says that the property `is not allowed`.

I also tried to point to different locations in `localRoot` and `remoteRoot` but it doesn't work also.

What can it be?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.

Seems like the `outFiles` in `launch.json` was causing the problem. After removing it and letting it to take the default value it worked. (As I understand this is for `yarn`).

It still starts the debugging in `tap` module, but if I press `f5` (the continue) it is stopping at the next breakpoint I set.